# Modifying salesforce reports before exporting using Apex

Tags: apex, reporting

I am struggling to find where to start w.r.t my following problem.
In SFDC reports, there is an "export details" button to export a user chosen report into csv or xls formats. I want to modify this xls file (for example, encrypt it) before user downloads it. I guess I can achieve this using Apex triggers. My questions are:
How can I add an Apex trigger which is triggered upon a user clicking this "export details" button?
How can I access the xls contents in this Apex trigger code where I want to encrypt them?
I extensively searched in Apex user guide and many other sources. I can not find how to add triggers to standard SFDC buttons.
Thank you very much in advance.

I asked this question on stackoverflow as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19997135/modifying-salesforce-reports-before-exporting-using-apex

Answer (score 1):

Triggers only fire on DML, and exports do not trigger DML, so you can't really modify the output of the reports with triggers. The data is transferred over the wire using TLS 1.0, meaning the data is encrypted while in transit; the users could choose to encrypt the file once downloaded using their operating system's features (e.g. Encrypting File System, or EFS) or with a third-party tool. You should note that a file encrypted on the server side would be useless for the user since they would have to have the appropriate key on their system, plus software, in order to decrypt the data in the file, which most likely would not be the case.

Comment: Thanks a lot sfdcbox. In my usecase, I want the user to contact the server to get the key to decrypt. I want to enforce DRM on sfdc reports somehow this way.

Comment: It's really "all or nothing" here. Either they can export reports, or they can't. You could build a custom "report" builder to allow limited data exports, and/or encrypted, etc using Visualforce.